# NFS сервер и ограничения по IP клиента

Tags: nfs

Есть Win10 ноут, к которому подключён сетевой диск(NFS на удаленном Ubuntu сервере), который используется как бекап/хранилище для разного мусора и не только.
Большую часть времени ноут находится дома, соответсвенно, IP у него "домашний", это IP и указан в настройках NFS Сервера, дабы закрыть сетевой диск от возможных залётных клиентов, которым нечего туда нос тыкать.

Внимание, вопрос:
Что можно придумать дабы ноут имел доступ к NFS с любого IP(не только с дома, а и мобильный интернет, вай фай на курорте/кафе/аэропорту), но чтобы никто левый не залез?
В данный момент, как идиот меняю настройки ВПН чтобы они соответствовали моему текущему айпи, если нужен удаленный диск, когда ноут не дома.

Кроме того, на сервере стоит L2TP VPN сервер. Думалось использовать его в данных целях (чтобы ноут через ВПН ловил айпи Сервера и Сервер думал что к диску подключаются по localhost), но что-то пошло не так и не сработало.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: хАчу сетевой диск, который будет работать при ЛЮБОМ IP Клиента, но при этом будет закрыт для несанкционированного доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Защита от *левых клиентов* по IP - это примерно как положить зарплату программиста в сейф, сейф закрыть картонкой и выставить на центральную площадь уездного города. Н - НАДЕЖНОСТЬ.

Правильное решение - использовать любой VPN, который нужно поднять на этом самом удаленном Ubuntu-сервере. [М-МАНУАЛ](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru)

Также на этом сервере надо наглухо закрыть файерволом доступ снаружи к NFS, более того, отключить в самом NFS прослушивание любых сокетов, кроме тех, которые открыты из интерфейса VPN.

И тогда *может быть* вас не сломают. Но это не точно.

Comment: L2TP VPN и так настроен, но, судя по всему, оно по какой-то причине не даёт никакого эффекта. В настройках NFS ставил как 127.0.0.1 так и адрес самого сервера - не работает =(

Comment: Так надо разбираться, что там не так. Но уж точно адрес не 127.0.0.1.

Comment: пробовал и  /var/nfs/general    127.0.0.1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
и /var/nfs/general    айписервера(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)

Comment: ну и какой айписервера вы туда засовывали? Тот, который ему присвоен в VPN, я надеюсь?